# JMeter- user defined variable not changing its value

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a Test Plan containing one Thread Group whith one HttpRequest sampler, JRS223PreProcessor and one csv data set config. I need to read from csv, at run time,the current value of column 2 and use it in my JSR223 PreProcessor. In order to do this, I defined a variable on Test Plan:

name  ${__CSVRead(C:/Users/marial/Desktop/csvs/csv_hotelCodeReq.txt,2)

In JSR223 PreProcessor I am taking it like this:

```
String name= new String(vars.get("name"));
```

I would expect this value to change on each line readed, but it didn't, it always take the first value encountered. Does anyone know why?

To be more specific, if I have the csv file :

1,2,firstName1:lastName1

3,2,firstName2:lastName2

and loop count = 2, users=1 than the values of name are:

loop1: firstName1:lastName1

loop2: firstName1:lastName1

The other values are correctly handled, so it goes to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

According to [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

So your [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) is evaluated **only during test startup and only once**

The solution would be moving the function into "Parameters" section of the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and you will be able to access the function output as `Parameters` in your Groovy script like:

```
String name = Parameters
```

Demo:

[image]

This way the __CSVRead() function will be executed each time the JSR223 PreProcessor is called. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is sort of usefull, but is not exactly what I am looking for. It works if I have 2 threads.. but I was searching for a solution that works for 1 thread(user) and 2 loop count. I tried this one, and now it always takes the second name, in my case. But anyway, I was able to find a solution for my problem, too.